# Which tag did I just earn Tag Editor privilege for?

Tags: support, tag-wikis

I just got a notification that I earned the Tag Editor privilege. Problem is I don't know which tag it was for. Is there a way to determine at a glance what tags you have Editor privileges for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misunderstand.

The [tag-wiki edit **privilege**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit-tag-wiki) is earned at 1,500 rep - which you've just past. This gives you the ability to create and edit tag wikis - short pieces of information that explain what the tag is about. It's not a badge.

To be able to edit tag wikis:

> .. editors must also either
>
> - be in the top 20 answerers for the tag, or
> - have a total score of 100 or more for the tag on non CW questions

Actually this isn't strictly true any more. If you are in the top 20 or have a score of 100 you will be able to edit as normal, but any user can propose an edit to tag wikis in the same way that they can propose edits to questions and answers. The edit must be approved by a user that meets the above criteria though.

Look in your profile to see which tags you have a score of 100 or more, and check the top users page ([C# Top Users](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/c%23/topusers)) where you'll see if you are in the top 20. You are currently 8th - so you can edit that tag wiki.

You will get the badge on your first edit to a tag-wiki body and it will be linked to from your profile page. See [which one I got it for on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/254/tag-editor?userid=59303).

Comment: I understand that...but how do I tell which tag-wiki I can edit? It doesn't show me which ones I'm top 20 or have 100 or more for off the bat.

Comment: @Mike - I've just realised You can actually edit tag-wikis with any rep now. Your edits are queued like edits to posts.

Comment: Ahh so the documentation is out of date.

Comment: Wait no...I'm over 1500 on SO and can't edit the MVVM Tag-wiki

Comment: @Mike - Odd. I've seen proposed tag wiki edits from low rep users and when I tried to edit one on Gaming I got a message telling me that my edit would be reviewed.